# Implementing Runnable and using Thread's methods within your own class

Tags: java, multithreading

They say that implementing Runnable is more preferrable than extending Thread. I agree that this is more Java-like.

Ok. I would like to do something like this:

```
public class HotThread implements Runnable {
...
    private void execute() {
        if (this.isInterrupted()) {
        ....
        }    
    }
}
```

So, now I get an error as there is no method isInterrupted. Could you help me understand this moment: how to use methods of the class Thread within your own class in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined in Thread class - `java.lang.Thread.isInterrupted()`

To use this

```
HotThread  ht = new HotThread();
Thread t = new Thread(ht);

use t.isInterrupted()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`isInterrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) is defined for the `Thread` but for the current thread you could use the shorthand form

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
```

Read: [Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)